# Handle Rebalancing of consumer group on addition of consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, rebalancing

I want to know how can we handle consumer group re-balancing in case of a new consumer being added to the group. As it automatically rebalances the partition assignment , the existing consumer running when try to process the batch and commit the offset fails.

Handing rebalancing or knowing when the rebalancing is occurring i can ignore the data processing and commit offset job and ask the consumer to poll the message again from committed offset.

Comment: Maybe you should add a rebalance listener? https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html

Comment: I am trying to implement the same in python. Do you have any sample /example for the same. I want to  capture functionality , if consumer  B adds to the group consumer A should come to know about it and stop processing the data till rebalance occurs.

Comment: That also exists in Python https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.subscribe + https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/kafka.html#kafka.ConsumerRebalanceListener